# How to integrate a Spring MVC application with Spring Cloud Gateway with OAuth2.0 Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Boot MVC + Thymeleaf application which talks to a bunch of microservices via Spring Cloud Gateway.

`mvc_app -> gateway -> (service_a, service_b,...)`

Now, I want to implement OAuth 2 based security and I want to centralize the authentication process at Gateway level.

That means:

1. If a user tries access a secured resource on any resource_servers (service_a, service_b, etc) via Gateway, Gateway should redirect the user to IdP Login Page.
2. After successful authentication, Gateway should use the accessToken to access the secured resource.

This can be achieved as follows:

1. Make gateway as OAuth 2 client using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and appropriate provider/client configuration
2. Use **TokenRelay** filter to forward the AccessToken to downstream resource_servers.

**The question:**

When you are authenticated by Gateway, the authentication state is maintained at Gateway application level. After successful authentication by Gateway, how do you send back the AccessToken, IdToken to `mvc_app` so that for further requests the same AccessToken will be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably reconsider your intentions: you want to use `TokenRelay` filter to bridge between a frontend secured with sessions and micro-services secured with tokens (resource servers), but you want to then provide the frontend with the tokens. What's the point?

Your Spring MVC frontend can be a reliable OAuth2 client. You should configure it as an OAuth2 "confidential" client (with `oauth2login`) and have the gateway be transparent to security (nothing at all there).

Spring REST clients (`WebClient`, `RestTemplate`, `@FeignClient`, even the new `RestClient`), are all designed to integrate with authorized client repository and transparently populate Authorization header with an access token in session. Refer to the manual of the one you chose for details.

Configuring the Gateway as an OAuth2 client with login and `TokenRelay` filter is of interest when the frontend is a SPA (Angular, React, Vue, ...) or a native app as it can't be a confidential client. And actually, you don't want to provide such application with the OAuth2 tokens: you have it authorized with just session (and CSRF) cookies and keep token safe on the server.

Comment: This makes sense. If we have SpringMVC app as client then we can make the app itself as Gateway and use TokenRelay for sending token to downstream calls. If we have an SPA instead of Spring MVC app as a client, then Gateway should be configured as a ResourceServer which just delegates to resources servers.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This is not exactly what I wrote. Yes, Gateway as OAuth2 client with `TokenElay` is a good fit for SPA. But token relay is specific for Gateway. Report to your REST client doc for integration with Spring OAuth2 clients (each have its own mechanisms). Also, **in both cases**, the resource servers are the REST APIs. If you read my answer again, I wrote that gateway should be transparent to OAuth2 when the front-end is an OAuth2 client.

Comment: I was exploring using Spring Cloud Gateway as an "OAuth Client" and "OAuth Resource Server" as described in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-oauth2

Comment: In my opinion, configuring the gateway as a resource server is an anti-pattern: either downstream services are not secured or access control is implemented twice. Moreover, this introduces tight coupling from the gateway to downstream services and makes access control rules impossible to unit test.

Comment: But this is not the only OAuth2 article at Baeldung I don't agree with. You can also find there articles recommending to build a single SecurityFilterChain with both OAuth2 client and OAuth2 resource server configuration which is, still in my opinion, a mistake. The same article also states that in this case the browser request are authorized with an access token, which is wrong.

Comment: I believe what is in [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth2_essentials) to be some better content. The BFF one covers the case with SPA & gateway as client with login and TokenRelay. The `resource-server_with_ui` one covers the case of an OAuth2 client MVC app with `@FeignClient` querying a resource server (no gateway in this tutorial, but as it should be transparent in that case, it wouldn't change a thing)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ch4mp. I heard about Spring Add-ons. I will take a look at it.